# Inequality involving changing order of limits and probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, limsup-and-liminf, time-series

I read [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2951764.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ae2f4dce81a81a85c622f5b85d3db7976&ab_segments=&origin=&initiator=), in Corollary 1 the author claims that $$\underset{\pi \in [0, 1]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) \overset{p}{\to} \infty$$ as $T \to \infty$. Where $W_T(\pi)$ is Wald statistics but I think it should not matter for my question.

The first step of the proof (formula A.35 in the paper) goes like this: Take any positive $c$,

$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [0, 1]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c) \le \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\sup\ \lim_{T \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c)$$
and then he proves that the expression on the RHS is zero.
For me it is unclear where this first inequality comes from. I think, using the monotone convergence theorem we can get
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [0, 1]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c)$$ but I do not think that in general we can say that $$\lim_{T \to \infty} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c) \le \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\sup\ \lim_{T \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\underset{\pi \in [\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]}{\sup}\ W_T(\pi) < c)$$ take for example $a_{T, \varepsilon} = 1\ \{ \frac{1}{\varepsilon} > T \}$ then $$1 = \lim_{T \to \infty} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} a_{T, \varepsilon} > \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\sup\ \lim_{T \to \infty} a_{T, \varepsilon} = 0$$

Do you have any ideas what is implicitly assumed in the proof to justify this step? Or am I missing something?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}$
I think the argument is simpler. Note that, if $A \implies B$, then $\bP(A) \leq \bP(B)$ (I use statements in place of events, I am sure you are fine with it).

Now fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Then clearly
$$
\sup_{\pi \in [0,1]} W_{T}(\pi) < c
\quad
\implies
\quad
\sup_{\pi \in [\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon]} W_{T}(\pi) < c,
$$
because the RHS is just a weaker statement. Hence,
$$
\bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [0,1]} W_{T}(\pi) < c\bigg)
\leq
\bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon]} W_{T}(\pi) < c \bigg),
$$
which implies
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty} \bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [0,1]} W_{T}(\pi) < c\bigg)
\leq
\lim_{T\to\infty} \bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon]} W_{T}(\pi) < c \bigg),
$$
(assuming that the limits exist). Since this statement holds for each $\varepsilon > 0$, it also holds for $\limsup_{\varepsilon\to 0}$:
$$
\limsup_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\lim_{T\to\infty} \bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [0,1]} W_{T}(\pi) < c\bigg)
\leq
\limsup_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\lim_{T\to\infty} \bP\bigg(\sup_{\pi \in [\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon]} W_{T}(\pi) < c \bigg).
$$
But the LHS does not depend on $\varepsilon$, so you arrive at the desired statement.

*Comment:* In your last example you do not have $a_{T,0} \leq a_{T,\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon,T$ (rather the other way around), so the argument would not go through here.